# How to rewind locally to a commit before the current state of repo?

Tags: git

The current state of remote repository breaks my code and I want to rewind locally to a previous commit, but I want to do it only on my machine, not to rewind the entire repo. How would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know the SHA1 of the commit you want?

```
git checkout SHA1
git checkout -b new_branch_name
```

You now have a local branch `new_branch_name` which you can continue working from.